# Задать регулярку, для того, чтобы выцепить температуру воды

Tags: регулярные-выражения

http://www.gismeteo.ru/city/legacy/34880/

Есть блок - температура воды. Как можно выцепить ее от туда?
Температуру воздуха уже выдернул так

```
preg_match_all("/\<td(\ class\=\"df\")?\>(.*)\<\/td>/",$data,$arr1);
```

Comment: preg_match_all("/\<div(\ id\=\"water\")?\>(.*)\<\/div>/",$data,$arr4);

пытался так, но выводит пустоту
array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну по-быстрому как-то так:

```
$d = file_get_contents('http://www.gismeteo.ru/city/legacy/34880/');
preg_match_all('/temp value m_temp c\">([0-9\+\-]{2,3})\</isu', $d, $m);
echo $m[1]; //+11
```